# Overflow: hidden on image hovering

Tags: css, overflow

Hi guys i have a flex gallery and i added a zoom on hover but the rule overflow hidden works only on width not height. This is the code.

```css
.brow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px
}


.column {
  flex: 15%;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 0 4px
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-box {
  width:auto;
  overflow:hidden; !important;
}
.image {
    width:auto;
  height:auto;
    background-position:center;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
} 
.image:hover {  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */ 
  transform: scale(1.2);
} 

.imagine {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.image:hover .imagine {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.image:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.texting {
  background-color: #0040ff;
border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brow">
  <div class="column">
<div class="image-box">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/Untitled-1.png" class="imagine"> <div class="middle">
   <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/formes_wtex-w6.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
    <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
  </div></div>
  <div class="column">
<div class="image-box">
   <div class="image"> <img src="https://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/napopsi.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
    <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/kapn.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
    <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
     <div class="image"><img src="https://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/napopsi.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
   <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
  </div></div>
  <div class="column">
<div class="image-box">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/καρτεσ.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
    <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/napopsi.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
   <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/napopsi.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
   <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
  </div> </div>
  <div class="column">
<div class="image-box">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/πσι.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
    <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
  </div></div>
  <div class="column">
<div class="image-box">
      <div class="image"> <img src="http://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%83.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
    <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
       <div class="image"> <img src="http://demostore.gr/images/promo/1/sta.jpg" class="imagine"><div class="middle">
    <a href="url"> <div class="texting">
Αμάνικα Μπουφάν
</div></a></div></div>
   </div></div>
</div>
```

I need this to work properly to transfer it to another similar website. If it helps the website is this [demostore](https://demostore.gr/). I tried it locally on my computer, i tried it on different websites to see if anything conflicts but it does the same problem everywhere so i suppose im doing something wrong. Sorry if i posted the code the wrong way but its my first time here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

image-box width getting overflow because the width is bound by the width of .column (having a fixed width of 15%).
but there is no fixed height for .column. therefore it taking the image height for image-box and your column having the same height (on hover / zoom too). since the height of your image and image-box is same there is no overflow.

Comment: I see, is it easy to give a fixed height on .column?

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood you, you mean that columns cant have a fixed height,so does this mean that i can't make it work with flex?